# Inserir cidades no banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Olá, estou criando uma base de dados, e nela terei informações dos municípios brasileiros, imagino que eu certamente não sou o primeiro a necessitar essas informações, porem eu não tenho conhecimento se existe alguma forma de fazer isso automaticamente, algum lugar que eu possa baixar essa base, ou algum script SQL que insira as informações no banco, porque fazer isso manualmente não é o mais aconselhável.

Estou utilizando o postgreSQL 9.3, não criei as tabelas para as cidades ainda.

Comment: O site do IBGE fornece todas as cidades por meio de alguns tipos de arquivo. Dê uma olhada nesse link, que já tem os sqls para postgre http://www.ferreiramauricio.com/sql-das-5565-cidades-brasileiras-segundo-dados-ibge-2010

Comment: Eu tenho um sql que eu uso, porém está para o `MySql`, mas acredito que com poucas alterações você poderá atingir seu objetivo. O arquivo está disponível em: [https://github.com/RichardSDias/SQL](https://github.com/RichardSDias/SQL/blob/master/Estados%20e%20cidades%20brasileiras.sql)

Comment: Todos os Estados e Municipios (ou quase todas...) do Brasil, com possibilidade de inserir novos paises, distritos/estados e municipios. (Colunas com prefixo para facilitar os JOINs e manter organização...). 

**Caso dê problema nos caracteres acentuados, abra o arquivo em um editor de texto qualquer e salve com codificação UTF-8, que resolve, ou copie e cole o código direto no MySQL (sem usar importação...)**

Vou deixar o link do projeto do **Github**: https://github.com/chinnonsantos/sql-paises-estados-cidades

Comment: Você pode usar o projeto open source que eu criei, ele busca diretamente na API do ibge e monta a lista mais atualizada possível de acordo com esses dados, segue o link
http://ibge-sql.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Código de cadastramento do IBGE

https://ferreiramauricio.s3.amazonaws.com/files/resource/24/brasil.mysql.sql

Copia tudo a partir do

```
CREATE TABLE cidades (
    id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome varchar(250),
    codigo_ibge integer,
    estado_id integer,
    populacao_2010 integer,
    densidade_demo numeric(10, 2),
    gentilico varchar(250),
    area numeric(10, 3),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

e executa no seu Postgre

> copiar também o CREATE TABLE citado acima

Comment: No link tem mysql, ele funcionara da mesma forma? não conheço as diferenças entre um e outro

Comment: @LucasMotta Sim, mysql e sql a maioria dos comandos são iguais